# Azure pipelines: Could not find any files to upload

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am quite new to azure pipelines,
I created a pipeline script to copy files to ftp once build is successful,

```
1. Install Nuget packages
2. Build the Project
3. Copy built files to FTP
```

but it is throwing could not find any files to upload error

```
    trigger:
    - master

    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'

    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'

    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:AppxPackageDir="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideloadOnly'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: FtpUpload@2
      inputs:
        credentialsOption: 'inputs'
        serverUrl: 'ftp://ba.foobar.com'
        username: 'Nitin'
        password: 'XKCD'
        rootDirectory: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
        filePatterns: '**'
        remoteDirectory: '/upload/$(Build.BuildId)/'
        enableUtf8: true
        clean: false
        cleanContents: false
        preservePaths: true
        trustSSL: true
```

help appreciated

Comment: Before you ask a question on Stack Overflow, a reasonable starting point is **validating your assumptions**. You said you "guess" it can't find the files. Validate that the files are where you expect them to be.

Comment: the files should be in `$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)` but it is throwing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments AppxPackageDir,  AppxBundle and UapAppxPackageBuildMode in your VSBuild are all actually unique arguments of UWP app which you can find more information at [Set up automated builds for your UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#configure-the-build-solution-build-task). Please make sure your project is a UWP app.

However, if it’s an Asp.net Core app which we can see in the Edit history. The corresponding should be:
 `msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'`. Please update your code and give it a try.

Comment: worked well, thank you, how do I make it build dll files instead a .zip file?

Comment: I suggest it's better to open a new thread for 'how to make it build dll files instead a .zip file' since this thread's question has been solved and it's a better practice that one question for one thread.